# Check if URL is Directory

Tags: c++, sftp, libcurl

I have this code to check if the path is Directory or File. Its works fine with FTP but not with SFTP. How do I check if path is Directory not file with libcurl?

```
bool IsDir(const wxString& path)
{ 

    wxString fullRemotePath = "sftp://user@server/home/user/";
    curl_easy_setopt(m_ftp, CURLOPT_URL, fullRemotePath.c_str().AsChar());
    curl_easy_setopt(m_ftp, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);//No transfer
    m_rc = curl_easy_perform(m_ftp);

    //reset back to normal
    curl_easy_setopt(m_ftp, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0L);

    return m_rc == CURLE_OK; //I expected it to fail on file, but it does not
}
```

**Curl Version is curl-7.43.0**

Comment: Check out the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477936/using-libcurl-to-check-if-a-file-exists-on-a-sftp-site). This was also discussed on the following [mailing-list](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-03/0004.html). One of both should help.

Comment: I tried both code in links and does not work either. I updated the curl version